# No serializer found while using mockito with Java 11

Tags: java, mockito, java-11

I created a test for my controller and service using mockito. While I use java 8 everything is Ok, but after migration to Java 11, I have this error. Maybe someone can help me fix this test?

```
public class ConfigurationControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @InjectMocks
    private ConfigurationController controller;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(controller)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void find() throws Exception {
        //given
        final ConfigurationsDto configDto = mock(ConfigurationsDto.class);
        given(configurationService.find(any())).willReturn(Arrays.asList(configDto));


        //when and then
        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/config/1.0.0/")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

After run, I recived https status 500 and error:

> [main] ERROR app.controllers.global.AdviceController - No serializer found for class org.mockito.internal.debugging.LocationImpl and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.Collections$SingletonList[0]->app.dtos.ConfigurationsDto$MockitoMock$534475338["mockitoInterceptor"]->org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor["mockHandler"]->org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler["invocationContainer"]->org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl["invocationForStubbing"]->org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher["invocation"]->org.mockito.internal.invocation.InterceptedInvocation["location"])

Of course, I add the needed dependency in pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just for a compatibility *You should check what is the underlying byte-buddy version, I guess it should be 1.9.0. Just make sure that with a direct dependency and confirm if it works or not.*

Comment: Check, still nothing change...

Comment: Try to upgrade jackson libraries to 2.9.7

Comment: I have 2.9.7 for jackson-databind and jackson-annotations

Comment: Please paste ObjectMapper/ObjectBuilder configuration

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430283/error-when-using-mockito-mocksomeobject-class-and-object-mapper and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658250/mock-interface-with-mockito-so-it-can-be-serialized-by-jackson. tl;dr: Mocks and Jackson don't play along well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fix this test using real object not mocked dto's

Comment: you can accept your own answer, so others can see right away that your question is solved.

Comment: I disagree, what if I want to use mocked dtos only. Usually in test env we don't use really objects.

Answer (score -1):

add following dependency fixed mine.

```
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
```