# Mock interface with Mockito so it can be serialized by Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

Havin a simple interface like

```
interface Foo {
  string getBar();
}
```

I want to mock it like

```
    final Foo foo = Mockito.mock(
      Foo.class,
      withSettings()
        .serializable(SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS)
        .withoutAnnotations()
        .stubOnly()
    );
```

And then be able to serialize it with Jackson.

When doing so, Jackson throws an exception

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.mockito.internal.junit.DefaultStubbingLookupListener]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.mockito.internal.junit.DefaultStubbingLookupListener and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.exampleuser.model.domain.Foo$MockitoMock$479459786["mockitoInterceptor"]->org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor["mockHandler"]->org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler["mockSettings"]->org.mockito.internal.creation.settings.CreationSettings["stubbingLookupListeners"]->java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList[0])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:293) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
```

If you wonder, the serialization happens in a REST Spring MVC controller, i return that interface in a spy

```
    doReturn(Optional.ofNullable(foo)).when(userService).getOne(anyLong(), any());
```

So it gets return in the controller like `ResponseEntity.ok(foo)`

Comment: Don't use a mock for this. Use a fake/stub/real object.

Comment: I am aware i could create a manual Stub class implementing this interface - but i would like to have this done with mock since this will be a general issue here, being in need to create manual interface stubs over and over again ( and maintain them over the course ). any other options then creating a `class FooMock extends Foo` implementation?

Comment: No. What you asking is beyond the purpose of a mock

Comment: You should consider the distinction between service classes / interfaces and data classes / interfaces. You should generally only marshal the latter and mock the former.

Comment: @johnb IMHO you are implying a lot without having any further details. E.g. in spring data you have projections, which are simple interfaces and are actually projections of "data classes" - if you want to instantiate them without a JPA context, you end up in a very similar situation - beside that it is not a projections here, but rather an `EntityView` of the `BlazePersistence` API. I need to mock those data-interfaces to be able to test  (mock/spy) REST-controller responses ( without JPA context

Comment: Generally, what I do in these cases is create a test implementation of the interface (hopefully using Lombok to reduce code) and create instances of the class for testing. Generally, I would have a "XyzTestSupplier" class that has reusable code to getting a valid populated instance of "Xyz" that all my tests can use. I would think this is less effort than mocking for DTOs. May not work in all cases but I have found it to be very effective.

Comment: Can you add an [mre] for this exception? From your question I got the impression that the exception happens if you pass a mock into `ResponseEntity.ok(...)` but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Passing a `mock` directly to jackson also does not cause an exception. But the serialized result is obviously not what you would expect from a normal class.