# Error when using mockito.mock(<SomeObject>.class) and object mapper

Tags: java, mockito, objectmapper

Im getting an InvalidDefinitionException when I try to map a mocked object with ObjectMapper. The object doesn't matter in that case. The code which produces the exception looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mock(Object.class));
```

The resulting exception message is this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyCrossClassLoaderSerializationSupport and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.mockito.codegen.Object$MockitoMock$nY0RyieU["mockitoInterceptor"]->org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor["serializationSupport"])
```

The ObjectMapper comes from jackson-databind v2.14.0, for mockito I'm using version 4.8.1

Comment: The reason for the exception is explained in the error message. What did you expect  / what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to achive ? What would you expected the string to look like?  The code you displayed can not worke. A mocked object is just a mock and not a real Object.

Comment: I'm just confused, because it used to work before I updated a few dependencies I guess. So the correct way would be to just create stubbed objects?

Comment: that's correct, but I don't need it for `new Object()`, I just used Object.class for simplification :) sorry, but I understood the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL; DR**

Mock objects aren't data structures, you can't serialize them by ObjectMapper.

**Full answer**

You are trying to serialize a mock object which is very special kind of object created by Mockito. It is very different from a ordinary data structures that are processable by ObjectMapper.

What ObjectMapper does is that it looks at the members of a serialized object and tries to serialize each of them. It either knows, how to do that (int, Long...), or it is configured (often right after a new instance creation), or the serialized member has some annotations to tell the ObjectMapper. In your case the mock object has a member of type ByteBuddyCrossClassLoaderSerializationSupport and the ObjectMapper has no idea what to do.